# Limit the amount of listitems stored in shared preferences

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences

I have a listview and a button in the listview item which when pressed adds the partucular listitem to my shared preferences by coverting the list item into JSON.
Everything works fine but i want to limit the number of listitems getting added to sharedpreferences say only 5 list items getting added in shared preferences and  if 6th listitem is added it should replace the 1st that is already added an so on.

Is this possible to do so

**this is my sharedpreference.java**

```
public class SharedPreference
{

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MY__APP"
public static final String FAVORITES = "app_Favorite";

public SharedPreference(){
    super();
}

public void saveFavorites(Context context, List<CodeList> favorites){
    SharedPreferences settings;
    Editor editor;

    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                                            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = settings.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(favorites);

    editor.putString(FAVORITES, jsonFavorites);

    editor.commit();
}

public void addFavorite(Context context, CodeList code){
    List<CodeList> favorites = getFavorites(context);

    if(favorites == null)
        favorites = new ArrayList<CodeList>();
    favorites.add(code);
    saveFavorites(context,favorites);
}

public void removeFavorite(Context context, CodeList code) {
    ArrayList<CodeList> favorites = getFavorites(context);
    if (favorites != null) {
        favorites.remove(code);
        saveFavorites(context, favorites);
    }
}


public ArrayList<CodeList> getFavorites(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    List<CodeList> favorites;
    //ArrayList<CodeList> favorites;

    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                                            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (settings.contains(FAVORITES)) {
        String jsonFavorites = settings.getString(FAVORITES, null);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        CodeList[] favoriteItems = gson.fromJson(jsonFavorites,
                                                 CodeList[].class);

        favorites = Arrays.asList(favoriteItems);
        favorites = new ArrayList<CodeList>(favorites);
        //favorites  = new ArrayList<CodeList>();
      //favorites.addAll(Arrays.asList(favoriteItems));
    } else
        return null;

    return (ArrayList<CodeList>) favorites;
    //return favorites;
}

}
```